# How to implement command line switches to my script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am a total newbie in python. I am writing a program that counts words, lines and characters. I started to have problems when I tried to use command line switches: -w, -l, -c, till then everything worked fine.

I read the posts on stackoverflow and python documentation about argparse but I don't now how to implement the argparse library and the code which is used with it.

When I run `python wc.py file.txt --l`

I get

> too many values to unpac

Can someone please help me with this?

```
from sys import argv
import os.path
import argparse

script, filename = argv


def word_count(filename):
    my_file = open(filename)
    counter = 0
    for x in my_file.read().split():
        counter += 1
    return counter
    my_file.close()

def line_count(filename):
    my_file = open(filename, 'r').read()
    return len(my_file.splitlines())
    my_file.close()

def character_count(filename):
    my_file = open(filename, 'r').read()
    return len(my_file)
    my_file.close()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--w', nargs='+', help='word help')
parser.add_argument('--l', nargs='+', help='line help')
parser.add_argument('--c', nargs='+', help='character help')
args = parser.parse_args()


if os.path.exists(filename):
    print word_count(filename), line_count(filename), character_count(filename)
else:
   print "There is no such file"
```

Comment: Look into e.g. `argparse`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `argparse` for argument parsing, you shouldn't be trying to parse `argv` yourself:

```
script, filename = argv
```

This is going to fail if `argv` has less than two elements:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wc.py", line 5, in <module>
    script, filename = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

*Or* if it has *more* than two elements:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wc.py", line 5, in <module>
    script, filename = argv
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

You instead want to use `argparse` to extract the filename from the argument list:

```
parser.add_argument('filename')
```

Your existing command line arguments could also use some fixing.  Instead of this:

```
parser.add_argument('--w', nargs='+', help='word help')
```

You want:

```
parser.add_argument('-w', action='store_true', help='word help')
```

This gives you a boolean option such that if the user passes `-w` then `args.w` will be `True`, otherwise `None`.  This gives you:

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

```
parser.add_argument('-w', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('filename')
args = parser.parse_args()


if os.path.exists(args.filename):
    print word_count(args.filename), line_count(args.filename), character_count(args.filename)
else:
   print "There is no such file"
```

You may also want to give your options long equivalents:

```
parser.add_argument('--words', '-w', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--characters', '-c', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--lines', '-l', action='store_true')
```

With this change, users can use either `-w` or `--words`, for example.  You will then have `args.words`, `args.characters`, and `args.lines` (instead of `args.w`, `args.c`, `args.l`).

Comment: Iarks you explained it very nice, just one more thing. Should I then define the variable filename at the top like
filename = 'someTxtFile.txt' ?

Comment: If I do that I get all the counts, not only for example number lines

Comment: You don't need a variable named `filename` because that value is already available as `args.filename`, as in the example I posted.  With your existing code you're not checking the values of your command line arguments to decide which count to show, so obviously you will need to implement that logic (`if args.words:`, etc).